# Can't install ios 9 simulator via xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have problem with Xcode 7.3.1 on OSX(10.11.4 El capitan) , namely, when i try to install any simulator using `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
i get this error:

```
could not download and install ios 9.1 simulator
when files are moved to the final location of an unexpected error occured
```

what's wrong?

here the log

```
Mac-Pro-USER:~ MAC$ sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Password:

2016-12-10 20:53:12.103 Xcode[3581:19770] Failed to locate a valid instance of CoreSimulatorService in the bootstrap.  Adding it now.

2016-12-10 20:53:12.297 Xcode[3581:19727] CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.

2016-12-10 21:10:24.889 Xcode[3581:19708] [MT] DVTDownloadable: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=120 "Could not download and install iOS 9.1 Simulator. could not download and install ios 9.1 simulator  when files are moved to the final location of an unexpected error occured." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not download and install iOS 9.1 Simulator. 
could not download and install ios 9.1 simulator
when files are moved to the final location of an unexpected error occured., arguments=(

    "-f",

    "-s",

    "/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware/C63C631F-0C12-4AAD-9864-7A0B007C6ACF.activeSandbox/Root",

    "/"

), NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff2fbfda940 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

2016-12-10 21:10:47.884 Xcode[3581:29128] This process won't be able to use DD remote data sources
```

Comment: What do you mean "using `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`". How are you trying to install? (Recommend to use Xcode8 stable from App Store btw.)

Comment: i mean that, initially i opened Xcode then-components then install simulator and got this error, on stackoverflow i found, that to download simulator i should via terminal using command
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode. But same error.

Could you give me direct link for 8 Xcode or Can I install it using terminal

Comment: Why are you using terminal at all? Just open Xcode, the app, in the normal way, and install any desired extra simulators from the Preferences pane.

Comment: When i open myapp. xcodeproject , i always get error, that this locked, and i don't know how to unlock, i did it in finder,but got error that parent category locked, but it's not true, i change attribute to read and write

Answer (score 0):

Open **Xcode**.

In the menu bar, click **Xcode** -> **Preferences**.

Once in the Preferences screen, click the **Components** tab.

Now, Click the **down arrow** next to the desired Simulator.

You can also check the validity of having saved each simulator by checking the directory where your simulators save.

Additionally, check the box that says "Check for and Install updates automtically" to avoid more problems of this nature.

Comment: I tried to do as you say, and got the same error :)

Comment: hmm.. Ok so here is a link to find your Simulator directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data

Comment: Use that, and open that directory (using Terminal command "open"), and make sure that there is no corruption in that directory.

Comment: Also, top-voted answers from here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551480/xcode-7-ios-simulators-missing-and-not-installable

Comment: If anything I have done is worth an upvote or a check, it would be greatly appreciated :)